# double click to enlarge the current console in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

Assume I've opened 4 console in tile layout and i want to double click one of them to be full screen. After that, double click to back to the tile layout. possible?

Comment: Not yet, may be in future

Comment: noted. in the roadmap? It'll be very useful.